# Scala value class compilation fails for base type with partial-function-parameter method

Tags: scala, higher-order-functions, partialfunction, value-class

Say, I defined a value class as follows

```
package object p {
  class ValueClass[T](val o: Option[T]) extends AnyVal {
    def foo: Option[T] =
      o collect {
        case t => t
      }
  }
}
```

The compilation failed with the message:

```
overriding method applyOrElse in trait PartialFunction of type [A1 <: T, B1 >: T](x: A1, default: A1 => B1)B1;
  method applyOrElse has incompatible type
       o collect {
                 ^
```

The error message seems not so meaningful to me as if I replace `collect` by `map` (which requires a function instead of a partial function) or the class does not extend `AnyVal`, the code snippet will compile.

Could anyone please explain the reason behind or link to a submitted issue?

Comment: With that same code, I get a different error: `implementation restriction: nested class is not allowed in value class This restriction is planned to be removed in subsequent releases.`

Comment: Which Scala version are you using? I'm aware that the restriction is removed in 2.10.3.

Comment: In 2.10.3 REPL I see what the OP got.

Comment: Ah yeah, I was using Eclipse IDE which had 2.10.1

Comment: Just out of curiosity are your trying to pimp the Option type or what's the use case? ;)

Comment: I was trying to do cool stuff with implicit value class, and yes, pimping.

Answer (score 6):

That's a good one. It works in 2.11.0-M8, at least.

Apparently,

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8011

with the exact match

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8018

On 2.10.x,

```
scala> trait X[A] { def pf: PartialFunction[A,A] = { case a => a } }
defined trait X

scala> class X[A](val x: A) extends AnyVal { def pf: PartialFunction[A,A] = { case a => a } }
<console>:7: error: overriding method applyOrElse in trait PartialFunction of type [A1 <: A, B1 >: A](x: A1, default: A1 => B1)B1;
 method applyOrElse has incompatible type
       class X[A](val x: A) extends AnyVal { def pf: PartialFunction[A,A] = { case a => a } }
                                                                            ^
```

Maybe this issue didn't come up after 2.10.3 allowed it.

For the morbidly curious, or idle, there were previously:

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6482

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7022 (duplicate)

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6187

OK, official validation that it was in fact a good one. This is the commit from which the back port was ported:

```
commit ff9f60f420c090b6716c927ab0359b082f2299de
Author: Paul Phillips <paulp@improving.org>
Date:   Sat Oct 6 10:20:45 2012 -0700

    Fix for SI-6482, lost bounds in extension methods.

    That was a good one. How to create a new method with type
    parameters from multiple sources, herein.
```

Update showing that 2.11.0-M8 does something:

```
apm@mara:~/goof$ scalam
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.0-M8 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_25).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> class X[A](val x: A) extends AnyVal { def pf: PartialFunction[A,A] = { case a => a } }
defined class X

scala> :pa -raw
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

package object p {
  class ValueClass[T](val o: Option[T]) extends AnyVal {
    def foo: Option[T] =
      o collect {
        case t => t
      }
  }
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.


scala> new p.ValueClass(Some(7)).foo
res0: Option[Int] = Some(7)
```

Comment: I don't have 2.11 on my machine, is it really fixed?

Comment: Well, thank you. Sorry I don't have enough reputation point to vote you up.

Comment: @user3281360 I don't pretend to understand the system. But if we create a jira ticket, we will earn points in heaven.

Comment: I was also trying to look it up in Jira and docs. Didn't find anything directly explaining how compiler would work with parameterized generic value classes, but none the less this is quite detailed doc: https://docs.google.com/document/d/10TQKgMiJTbVtkdRG53wsLYwWM2MkhtmdV25-NZvLLMA/edit?hl=en_US.

Comment: To me it looked like a bug because the code kinda made sense and all types would check.

Comment: We need to read that or this http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html before trying, no?